# 2000ms to run far to slow

Tags: performance, optimization, task

```
       private void SetState(int i)
    {






        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
           {
               Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
               sw.Start();

               if (getCannonState(i) == 0)
                   state = 0;                      
                if (getCannonState(i) == 1)                      
                        state = 1;
                if (getCannonState(i) == 2)                      
                        state = 2;                   
                if (getCannonState(i) == 3)                       
                        state = 3;
             if (getCannonState(i) == 4)
            state = 4;

               sw.Stop();
               Console.WriteLine("Set state of cannon " + i + " took {0} milliseconds", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());


           });



    }
```

Herer is my code . get cannonstate gets a screen shot and checks for pixels. any how running getcannon state runs at 397ms. yet running setstate takes 2000 ms. why is it so slow? i need it get recive information from getcannonstate and quickly set the state.

ive been trying to use tasks but no such luck.

Comment: I supose your code is `C#`?

Comment: You should show what happens inside the getCannonState(i) mathod, as this seems to be the slow part. And you should not call it several times but store the result.
Besides this it is quite unclear what you intend to do at all ... Please provide some context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the script take so long because you call getCannonState 5 times... assing the result to a variable to fix the problem and call getCannonState only once ;)

```
private void SetState(int i) {
  var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    var state = getCannonState(i);

    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Set state of cannon " + i + " took {0} milliseconds", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());

  });
}
```

Comment: Nice, this should work if there is no side-effects in getCannonState.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `getCannonState(i)` 5 times. You should save it in a local variable and check this:

```
var checkState = getCannonState(i);
if (checkState == 0) 
   ...
```

But looking to your code, it's even possible to assign the value directly to `state`

```
state = getCannonState(i);
```